# Cannot See Full Filenames in Android File Picker

Tags: android

I don't know if I'm missing something, but I have found no way to distinguish long file names in the Storage Access Framework file picker if they start with the same characters. It only shows the start of the filename if it is long, and what shows is the same for all those files as in this screenshot:

[image: Scteenshot]

This is on a Galaxy S22 Ultra running Android 13. You can turn it sideways, but that also doesn't work if the names are very long.

Comment: As with many things in Android, the UI for this screen may vary by manufacturer and device. You're welcome to file a bug report against Android itself, to at least have the stock implementation do something here (e.g., long press to show a `Toast` with the name).

Comment: There is nothing u can do about this ...